# Joomla JText::_("")

Tags: php, joomla

Im trying to change the language of a Joomla! component called DigiCom. Actually I don't understand this line here:

```
<th class="text-center"><?php echo JText::_("COM_DIGICOM_PRICE_PLAN");?></th>
```

I guess this might be a reference, as the text displayed is not COM_DIGICOM_PRICE_PLAN. If I am right, do you know where can I change it?

Here is part of the code:

```
<?php
/**
 * @package     DigiCom
 * @author      ThemeXpert http://www.themexpert.com
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2010-2015 ThemeXpert. All rights reserved.
 * @license     GNU General Public License version 3 or later; see LICENSE.txt
 * @since       1.0.0
 */

defined('_JEXEC') or die;


JHTML::_('behavior.formvalidation');

$pg_plugin = $this->pg_plugin;
$configs = $this->configs;
$data = $this->data;
?>
<div id="digicom" class="dc dc-checkout">

    <?php
    $this->setLayout('cart');
    echo $this->loadTemplate('steps');
    ?>

    <h1 class="page-title"><?php echo JText::sprintf("COM_DIGICOM_CHECKOUT_PAYMENT_DETAILS_PAGE_TITLE", $pg_plugin); ?></h1>

    <div class="dc-checkout-items">

        <h4 class="align-center"><?php echo JText::_("COM_DIGICOM_SUMMARY_YOUR_ORDER");?></h4>
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[`JText::_()`](https://docs.joomla.org/JText/_()) is a helper function to help with localization. It will take a symbol like `COM_DIGICOM_PRICE_PLAN` and lookup the users currently set language and pull the related string from the associated language file. These language files are located under the `/language` and `/administrator/language` folders.

If there is no matching symbol the function will simply return the passed symbol. So, if `COM_DIGICOM_PRICE_PLAN` was not found in the component's language files, it would just give back `COM_DIGICOM_PRICE_PLAN`. Otherwise, it will give back the associated string.

So, if you are wanting to change a component's localization strings you need to do one of two things. 1) edit the language file, or 2) add an override.

**To edit the language file:**

Find the component/module/plugin's language file. Find the associated symbol and change the string.

That particular component's language `filename/path` would be something like

```
/language/en-GB/en-GB.com_digicom.ini
/administrator/language/en-GB/en-GB.com_digicom.ini
/administrator/language/en-GB/en-GB.com_digicom.sys.ini
```

Where `en-GB` is the particular language you want to change (or go through all of them, if you want to change the string for all languages).

Then, look for a line like

```
COM_DIGICOM_PRICE_PLAN="Some text"
```

After that, just change `Some Text` to whatever you would like it changed to.

[Read the Joomla component tutorial about adding language management](https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Developing_an_MVC_Component/Adding_language_management) to learn more

Note though these files may be overwritten when updating the component, so you may have to re-edit those if it does ever update.

**Add an override**

This is a better option as you do not need to edit/re-edit any files after an update.

Go to the **Languages: Overrides** page and add an override for the language constant. You can get there by accessing menu in the backend and going to  `Extensions -> Languages -> Overrides`

There just put in the constant you want to override: `COM_DIGICOM_PRICE_PLAN` and then the text you want to appear. Then save.

[image]